# Hide row in excel by mouseover of particular cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am using `=Hyperlink` in a series of cells in a worksheet to call a public function that changes the value of a particular cell. It works very well. But I want the function to hide a row when I mouse over a particular cell. Can anyone help?

The code is:

```
Public Function highlightcell(seriesName As Range)
    Range("valSelOption") = seriesName.Value
'enter code here to hide Row 1

End Function
```

Comment: I believe row can be made hidden on cell selection but using mouseover of particular cell seems not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
    Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 0
```

As an easy way to hide row 1

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Answer**
There is no On Mouseover event in Excel.

This thread shows how you can achieve something similar using selection change, but it wont work for what you want.
http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=147219

**Hiding a Row**
Use this code:

```
ActiveSheet.Rows(2).Hidden=True
```

This will hide row 2.

**Explaining Events in Excel**
If you want the worksheet to react to the user (clicking a cell, changing a cell, calculating the sheet, opening the workbook, etc) you want to use Excel Events. This is a good explanation of Excel Events:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh211482(v=office.14).aspx